# What does two slasshes mean in a unix file system?

Tags: unix

Here is my code:

```
find ./ -name Desktop -type d   
.//Desktop
find: .//Documents/Library: Permission denied
```

Why two slashes following the period.? What does .// mean?I thought in Unix, the file system is named after appending one slash at the END of the folder name? Hence Documents/ means the document directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have no special meaning. Your find is just outputting prefix './' + path found. (try with `.` instead of `./`, or with no path specification at all, i.e. `find -name Desktop -type d`!).

Under POSIX filesystems, `directory//abc` is the same as `directory/abc`.

> Hence Documents/ means the document directory.

no, the directory is called "Documents" (and its full path is probably something like `/home/jxhyc/Documents`).

*Some* commands (e.g. `rsync`) interpret a trailing slash as "treat this differently than a normal file", but that's not Unix semantics, that's up to the individual program.